# MySQL MATCH AGAINSTполнотекстовый поиск по части e-mail с символом @

Tags: mysql, request, полнотекстовый-поиск

Задача - найти почту по совпадению от одного символа при совпадении от начала.

при попытке найти почту "test@berloga.com" по части email "test@ber" (запрос1) - выдает ошибку `syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting $end`

(запрос1)

```
select clientName, Client.email
from Client 
where MATCH(Client.email) AGAINST('test@ber*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

если часть почты заключить в кавычки `AGAINST('"test@ber*"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` - то поиск не выдает ничего.

если записать вместо "@"  символ "+", `AGAINST('test+ber*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`, то выдает и искомый имейл и те которые не искал

- berloga@test.com
- test@berloga.com
- test5@berloga.uf

У кого-то есть подсказки как решить данную проблему с полнотекстовый поиском не используя LIKE?

Comment: Мне кажется, вы просто применяете неподходящий к задаче механизм. С другой стороны, если посмотреть на выдаваемые scores по поиску 'test ber', то можно получить удовлетворительные результаты.

Comment: дело в том, что поиск по почте это только часть глобального поиска по имени, почте и еще нескольким полям и символ @ ломает везде запрос. А с + выдает значения которые не ожидаются. Но я же не первый, кто сталкивался с такой задачей, неужели никто не решил ее "не криво"

Comment: В парадигме полнотекстового поиска эти "неожиданные" значения очень даже ожидаются. Вы, образно говоря, используете операцию конкатенации для строк "11" и "22" и удивляетесь, что результат "1122", а не 33.

Comment: вообще-то я бы с радостью получил бы 11@22 - но еще не нашел как этот вопрос решается :). Почему полнотекст не находит test@ber* - для меня загадка

Comment: И при этом спрашиваете, как получить 33 (в моей аналогии) без использования арифметического сложения, ибо не первый же вы, кто столкнулся с этой проблемой :)

Answer (score 1):

[Boolean Full-Text Searches](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

> InnoDB full-text search **does not support** the use of the `@` symbol in boolean full-text searches. The `@` symbol is reserved for use by the @distance proximity search operator.

Всё. Мысль остановилась.

---

PS. А для озвученной задачи полнотекстовый поиск вообще не нужен, можно обойтись вульгарным `WHERE INSTR(Client.email, 'test@ber')`.

Comment: у меня поисковая фраза ходит по разным полям в том числе и в поле имя, куда некоторые пользователи пишут имя в виде "@Gadya Petrofich". Так вот нужно выдавать такую запись именно по "@Gadya". А если в поле имя записано как  просто Gadya, то не должно выдавать по запросу @Gadya. Если @ игнорируется даже в "обертке", то я очень сильно озадачен.